# OpenCV, Python: How to use mask parameter in ORB feature detector

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, feature-detection

By reading a few answers on stackoverflow, I've learned this much so far:

The mask has to be a `numpy` array (which has the same shape as the image) with data type `CV_8UC1` and have values from `0` to `255`.

What is the meaning of these numbers, though? Is it that any pixels with a corresponding mask value of zero will be ignored in the detection process and any pixels with a mask value of 255 will be used? What about the values in between?

Also, how do I initialize a `numpy` array with data type `CV_8UC1` in python? Can I just use `dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1`

Here is the code I am using currently, based on the assumptions I'm making above. But the issue is that I don't get any keypoints when I run `detectAndCompute` for either image. I have a feeling it might be because the mask isn't the correct data type. If I'm right about that, how do I correct it?

```
# convert images to grayscale
base_gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.base, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
curr_gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.curr, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)

# initialize feature detector
detector = cv2.ORB_create()

# create a mask using the alpha channel of the original image--don't
# use transparent or partially transparent parts
base_cond = self.base[:,:,3] == 255
base_mask = np.array(np.where(base_cond, 255, 0))

curr_cond = self.base[:,:,3] == 255
curr_mask = np.array(np.where(curr_cond, 255, 0), dtype=np.uint8)

# use the mask and grayscale images to detect good features
base_keys, base_desc = detector.detectAndCompute(base_gray, mask=base_mask)
curr_keys, curr_desc = detector.detectAndCompute(curr_gray, mask=curr_mask)

 print("base keys: ", base_keys)
 # []
 print("curr keys: ", curr_keys)
 # []
```

Comment: "how do I initialize a numpy array" -- Did you try reading the [numpy documentation on data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)?

Comment: The question is, to what data type on that list does CV_8UC1 correspond? I'm inclined to believe that it's uint8 because of the 8 and the U, although I haven't found any documentation confirming that. The issue is that I'm not getting any keypoints from that

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html -- first paragraph. You got it right, `uint8`. | Inspect the masks and make sure they make sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So here is most, if not all, of the answer:

> What is the meaning of those numbers

0 means to ignore the pixel and 255 means to use it. I'm still unclear on the values in between, but I don't think all nonzero values are considered "equivalent" to  255 in the mask. See [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/103087/behaviour-of-orb-keypoint-detection-with-masks/).

> Also, how do I initialize a numpy array with data type CV_8UC1 in python?

The type CV_8U is the unsigned 8-bit integer, which, using numpy, is `numpy.uint8`. The C1 postfix means that the array is 1-channel, instead of 3-channel for color images and 4-channel for rgba images. So, to create a 1-channel array of unsigned 8-bit integers:

```
import numpy as np
np.zeros((480, 720), dtype=np.uint8)
```

(a three-channel array would have shape `(480, 720, 3)`, four-channel `(480, 720, 4)`, etc.) This mask would cause the detector and extractor to ignore the entire image, though, since it's all zeros.

> how do I correct [the code]?

There were two separate issues, each separately causing each keypoint array to be empty.

First, I forgot to set the type for the `base_mask`

```
base_mask = np.array(np.where(base_cond, 255, 0)) # wrong
base_mask = np.array(np.where(base_cond, 255, 0), dtype=uint8) # right
```

Second, I used the wrong image to generate my `curr_cond` array:

```
curr_cond = self.base[:,:,3] == 255 # wrong
curr_cond = self.curr[:,:,3] == 255 # right
```

Some pretty dumb mistakes.

Here is the full corrected code:

```
# convert images to grayscale
base_gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.base, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
curr_gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.curr, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)

# initialize feature detector
detector = cv2.ORB_create()

# create a mask using the alpha channel of the original image--don't
# use transparent or partially transparent parts
base_cond = self.base[:,:,3] == 255
base_mask = np.array(np.where(base_cond, 255, 0), dtype=np.uint8)

curr_cond = self.curr[:,:,3] == 255
curr_mask = np.array(np.where(curr_cond, 255, 0), dtype=np.uint8)

# use the mask and grayscale images to detect good features
base_keys, base_desc = detector.detectAndCompute(base_gray, mask=base_mask)
curr_keys, curr_desc = detector.detectAndCompute(curr_gray, mask=curr_mask)
```

TL;DR: The mask parameter is a 1-channel `numpy` array with the same shape as the grayscale image in which you are trying to find features (if image shape is `(480, 720)`, so is mask).

The values in the array are of type `np.uint8`, `255` means "use this pixel" and `0` means "don't"

*Thanks to [Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) for leading me to parts of this answer.*